# Getting wrong ids in an eloquent query

Tags: laravel

I made a query who return me results with also `"Licencies"` from `structure_id` who are differents from = `4` . everything is good good with just the where clause but if i had another condition with an orWhere then the query display me also resultat from differents `structure_ids ...` Anyone knows the right query to got only the good structure id with the two where clause ? thanks a lot in advance

here my query :

```
$licencies = Licencies::where('structure_id' ,  '4')->where('statut_licence_id' , '2')->orWhere('valid_licence_id' , '1')->get();
```

here the query when i run the code :

```
select * from `licencies` where `structure_id` = '4' and `statut_licence_id` = '2' or `valid_licence_id` = '1'
```

but in the result i get also licencies from structure_id = 5 for exemple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all the records having the structure_id 4, but with statut_licence_id '2' or valid_licence_id 1, try this:

```
$licencies = Licencies::where('structure_id' , '4')
->where(function($query) {
     $query->where('statut_licence_id' , '2')
           ->orWhere('valid_licence_id' , '1')
 })->get();
```

Take a look at Parameter grouping in the link here : https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 1):

You can find more about using multiple where clauses at the Query Builder documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#parameter-grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : (btw you have 3 different ids... structure_id, statut_licence_id,  valid_licence_id ) make sure you have the logic correct because your query seems  to be okay.

```
$licencies = Licencies::where(['structure_id' => '4','statut_licence_id' => '2'])->orWhere('valid_licence_id' => '1')->get();
```

Its logic to have  licencies from structure_id = 5, because if valid_licence_id its 1 (which will match with your OR statement) then structure_id why not be 5?

Comment: thanks for your reply ! it's not working the query is correct till the orwhere clause . then when i put the orwhere clause i get all the others licences from other structure_id

Comment: yes I know because you just check `valid_licence_id` in your or statement so  `structure_id`  could be anything